# Ipad 3 cover not deactivating screen

Tags: ipad

My iPad 3 with the original apple cover seems to stay turned on (display is on) when the cover is closed. This causes massive battery drain. Restarting did not fix this issue.

Anyone here has the same issue or any solutions?

Comment: When you go to `Settings -> Display & Brightness` is the Lock/Unlock turned on?

Comment: Yes that is enabled. Was working fine up until yesterday.

Comment: There's not much to troubleshoot with these things. You can try to put a magnet against the right side of the iPad, toward the middle, to see if it's just the cover's magnets not working properly.  I'm assuming you don't have another device or cover to test with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the cover itself was somehow the issue. After trying out a magnet which was working, a friend came over who also has a cover for the iPad. It's working with his cover. My cover is also not working on his iPad.